# strange response headers in laravel app using JWT

Tags: laravel, authorization, jwt, token

I encountred a very strange response from my request you see I'm using JWT using a header called 'Authorization', but no matter what I did it wont reach my api, but here is the strange thing when I put any random header it reaches the api, this baffles me because I want the header to reach in the name 'Authorization'.

does laravel filter this header out?

Comment: already tried all those solutions none of them worked

Comment: This is no reason to ask the same question again.